# Module to pool streams in node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a two readable/writable streams:

- `fileDataToUrlStream()` takes file chunks like those emitted from `ReadableFileStream` and emits URL's
- `urlToParsedDataStream()` takes those URL's, downloads the data, and then emits data parsed from the download

I've currently got it hooked up like this:

```
process.stdin
  .pipe(fileDataToUrlStream())
  .pipe(urlToParsedDataStream())
  .pipe(process.stdout);
```

The problem is this all runs serially. `urlToParsedDataStream` doesn't consume
data until it's made the request and emitted the data.

I'd like to have a pool of say 10 or so `urlToParsedDataStream()`'s such that
at any given time I've got at most 10 requests in flight. How do I accomplish
this? There has to be an existing npm module, right?

[This](https://github.com/Obvious/pipette#cat) looks close, but I don't need
the data to be emitted in the same order as the streams are passed in.

Comment: Not a real answer to your question, because does not involve a new stream. But: just use `async.queue` -- it's exactly what you are looking for, but w/o streams. Consume `fileDataToUrlStream` and feed its output as `async.queue` tasks. The tasks themselves invoke the logic within `urlToParsedDataStream` and write to `stdout`. If you *must* use `urlToParsedDataStream()` as is, and can't use its internals, then I suppose you'll have to write a stream to do as I described. It will be duplex, and will have to buffer its output it case it hasn't been piped with a stream to drain to.

Comment: thanks! i think this could work. the only thing is i don't want to consume anything from `fileDataToUrlStream()` unless there's a free worker (otherwise i could end up just consuming loads of memory). is there a way to do this? it looks like i'd need to wrap it w/ a stream that doesn't push the item until `q.length()` is < `concurrency`. how do i signal that backpressure to the stream that's been piped in?

Comment: First of all, *how* much memory, exactly? It's only a list of URLs, no? But for the sake of exercise: each worker, when finishing and after calling its callback, will also consume one more item from `fileDataToUrlStream()` and add to the queue. You can also consume and add to queue in the queue's `drain` callback (loop, checking for `q.length()`, until it's "long enough"). You could also use "traditional" methods: call `pause()` on the stream when `q.length()` is "large enough", and in every worker, after calling callback, consider calling `resume()` on the incoming stream.

Comment: i'm scraping the [TREC conference's microblog data set](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:AuI32R4M5xwJ:trec.nist.gov/data/tweets/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us), so it's a list of 16 million twitter urls.

Comment: i dunno... honestly i'm waiting on the dataset, so in the meantime i'm prematurely optimizing :) i think this gives me the info i need though, thanks!

Comment: So feel free to accept if I post as an answer. Btw 16M urls is approx. 80Mb, not so terrible at all.